# Lexer in C#(for procedure Pascal) That Uses Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex, lexer

Help verify the correctness of the input procedure in the Pascal language. Please.

Identifiers, string constants enclosed in double quotes and single characters enclosed in single quotes can be used as parameters.

True

```
proc1('s',13,"sss");
proc2('s',s,d,11,"sss");
proc3("sss");
```

False

```
proc1(s',11,"sss"); 
proc2('s',s,d,11,sss");
proc3("sss);
proc4("sss";
```

My pathetic attempt:

```
public void ThreadPoolCallback(Object threadContext)
    {
        if ((str.Length == 0) && (str[str.Length - 1] != ')'))
        {
            haveError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            int startIndex = str.IndexOf('('),
            lastIndex = str.LastIndexOf(')'),
            startIndex2 = str.LastIndexOf('('),
            lastIndex2 = str.IndexOf(')');
            if (startIndex < lastIndex && startIndex > 0 && lastIndex == str.Length - 1 &&
            startIndex == startIndex2 && lastIndex == lastIndex2)
            {
                int curr = startIndex + 1;
                while (curr < lastIndex)
                {
                    string s = "";
                    while (str[curr] != ',' && curr < lastIndex)
                    {
                        s += str[curr];
                        curr++;
                    }

                    curr++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                haveError = true;
            }
        }
        doneEvent.Set();
    }
```

Comment: Is your `str` variable contains `proc` and a number also?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand your

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not build the whole Pascal engine into this regex, but it should do what you want:

```
@"\((?:(?:'[\d\w_]+'|""[\d\w_]*""|[\d\w_]+),?)*\);"
```

It will match from the start parenthes '`(`' numbers and letters surrended by single or double quotes (matching pairs) or letters and numbers followed by an optional comma '`,`' and ending in a end parenthes '`)`' and a semicolon '`;`'.

How to use:

```
string test = "proc1('s',13,"sss");\n" + "proc2('s',s,d,11,"sss");\n"
+ "proc3("sss");" + "proc1(s',11,"sss");" + "proc2('s',s,d,11,sss");"
+ "proc3("sss);" + "proc4("sss";";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"\((?:(?:'[\d\w_]+'|""[\d\w_]*""|[\d\w_]+),?)*\);");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(test))
{
    Console.Write(match.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry, I can't raise your reputation, not the masses of points.

Comment: Hehe, no problem.